# Adding Multiple Markers to Google Maps using json file

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps

I have a map and a JSON file containing information on Restaurants. I need to add markers to the map for 20 of the restaurants from the JSON file, but I just can't get the map to load with the markers on. I don't think i'm retrieving the data from the JSON file correctly. A point in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
  var map;
    function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(55.9753905, -1.6236163),
            zoom: 12,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

       map = new 
         google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("EstablishmentCollection"),
           mapOptions);
           $.getJSON("'FHRS_json.json'", function(json1) {
           $.each(json1, function(key, data) {
               var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
               // Creating a marker and putting it on the map
               var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                   position: latLng,
                   title: data.BusinessName
               });
               marker.setMap(map);
               });
            });
```

And then this is sample of the start of the JSON file. There's loads of restaurants so I wont post it all.

```
 {
   "FHRSEstablishment": {
   "-xmlns:xsi": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance",
   "Header": {
   "ExtractDate": "2018-02-03",
   "ItemCount": "2369",
   "ReturnCode": "Success"
  },
"EstablishmentCollection": {
      "EstablishmentDetail": [
        {
          "FHRSID": "1011573",
          "LocalAuthorityBusinessID": "17/00395/MIXED",
          "BusinessName": "#Central",
          "BusinessType": "Pub/bar/nightclub",
          "BusinessTypeID": "7843",
          "AddressLine1": "15 Marlborough Crescent",
          "AddressLine2": "Newcastle upon Tyne",
          "PostCode": "NE1 4EE",
          "RatingValue": "AwaitingInspection",
          "RatingKey": "fhrs_awaitinginspection_en-GB",
          "RatingDate": { "-xsi:nil": "true" },
          "LocalAuthorityCode": "416",
          "LocalAuthorityName": "Newcastle Upon Tyne",
          "LocalAuthorityWebSite": "http://www.newcastle.gov.uk/",
          "LocalAuthorityEmailAddress": "psr@newcastle.gov.uk",
          "SchemeType": "FHRS",
          "NewRatingPending": "False",
          "Geocode": {
            "Longitude": "-1.62244200000000",
            "Latitude": "54.96785900000000"
          }
        },
```

Comment: Need to show what comes before `"EstablishmentCollection"` in the json in order to accurately point at the array in `"EstablishmentDetail"` which is what you need to access. Also the values you need are in `Geocode.Latitude` and `Geocode.Longitude`. There is no `data.lat` or `data.lng`

Comment: @charlietfl i've added the begininning of the JSON file on, and oh yes! I'll change that thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think the main problem you're having is you need to parse the floats. Currently they are just strings. You can create a marker with the following function. Just pass the establishment as an object into the function and it will create the marker for you:

```
   function createMarker(obj) {
        const LatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(
            parseFloat(obj.geocode.Latitude),
            parseFloat(obj.gecode.Longitude)
        );    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: LatLng,
            map: map,
            title: obj.BusinessName
        });
    }
```

Comment: oh isee! would I replace obj with EstablishmentDetail? Sorry for the basic questions, i'm not too skilled with this.

Comment: Yes you would pass in The EstablishmentDetail object

Comment: So you would essentially put it in a for each loop passing in EstablishmentDetail[i]

Comment: @charlietfl no I do not. I’m essentially doing the same in the markers options with map: map. After all that’s what setMap does ;)

Comment: My bad...missed that

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the loop to:

```
$.each(json1.EstablishmentCollection.EstablishmentDetail, function(key, data) {

  var coords = data.Geocode;
  //look in browser console for errors and/or proper lat/lng object
  console.log(coords)


  var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(+coords.Latitude, +coords.Longitude);
  // Creating a marker and putting it on the map
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latLng,
    title: data.BusinessName
  });
  marker.setMap(map);
});
```

Comment: i've replaced the loop with that^^^ but my map doesn't load at all :/

Comment: the error in console says : Uncaught Jb {message: "initialize is not a function", name: "InvalidValueError", stack: "Error↵    at new Jb (https://maps.googleapis.com/m…T0Up42whRQeyw7X6UG9EAY&callback=initialize:156:51"}

Comment: Did you declare `function initialize()` inside another function?

Comment: Works fine here using same json stored remote. http://jsfiddle.net/z1jsmu2w/1/ My guess is you didn't declare `initialize()` before loading google maps library. ( I saw same thing happen and same error)

Comment: oh okay, how did get it to work after getting the error ?

Comment: Make sure script tag with `function initialize()` is before the one that loads the maps library

Comment: yey! it's kind of working, it's displaying some markers, and i've got another error saying it doesn't recognise Latitude but I do have some markers showing so i'ts progress. Thank you for you help!

Comment: there's the occasional ones that don't have the properties but there's quite a few that do yet only 11 markers show, I need 20 in total but I would have thought all the ones with that geocode would show because there's still hundreds that do have the geocode properties :/

Comment: Ok but if you run into error can block other code. Check for those properties on each object inside the loop before trying to create LatLng and marker

Comment: ohhh okay isee thanks, so would ihave to change the property?

Comment: Or just do `if(data.Geocode && data.Gecode.Latitude && data.Gecode.Longitude)`

Comment: do I put this before the LatLng and Marker Variables? sorry for all the questions, i'm not very good at this @charlietfl

Comment: yes....then only do the markers inside the `if()` when those properties actually exist. Otherwise do nothing

Answer (score 1):

Change your loop processing to process over the **array** in the JSON data:

```
$.each(jsonData.EstablishmentCollection.EstablishmentDetail, function(key, data) {
  var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.Geocode.Latitude, data.Geocode.Longitude);
  // Creating a marker and putting it on the map
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latLng,
    title: data.BusinessName
  });
  marker.setMap(googleMap);
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/8spxpjyL/2/)

**code snippet:**

```css
html,
body,
#googleMap {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="googleMap"></div>
<script>
  function initialize() {

    var center = new google.maps.LatLng(54.9753905, -1.6236163);
    var mapCanvas = document.getElementById("googleMap");
    var mapOptions = {
      center: center,
      zoom: 12
    };
    var googleMap = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
    $.each(jsonData.EstablishmentCollection.EstablishmentDetail, function(key, data) {
      var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.Geocode.Latitude, data.Geocode.Longitude);
      // Creating a marker and putting it on the map
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latLng,
        title: data.BusinessName
      });
      marker.setMap(googleMap);
    });
  }
</script>
<script>
  var jsonData = {
    "EstablishmentCollection": {
      "EstablishmentDetail": [{
        "FHRSID": "1011573",
        "LocalAuthorityBusinessID": "17/00395/MIXED",
        "BusinessName": "#Central",
        "BusinessType": "Pub/bar/nightclub",
        "BusinessTypeID": "7843",
        "AddressLine1": "15 Marlborough Crescent",
        "AddressLine2": "Newcastle upon Tyne",
        "PostCode": "NE1 4EE",
        "RatingValue": "AwaitingInspection",
        "RatingKey": "fhrs_awaitinginspection_en-GB",
        "RatingDate": {
          "-xsi:nil": "true"
        },
        "LocalAuthorityCode": "416",
        "LocalAuthorityName": "Newcastle Upon Tyne",
        "LocalAuthorityWebSite": "http://www.newcastle.gov.uk/",
        "LocalAuthorityEmailAddress": "psr@newcastle.gov.uk",
        "SchemeType": "FHRS",
        "NewRatingPending": "False",
        "Geocode": {
          "Longitude": "-1.62244200000000",
          "Latitude": "54.96785900000000"
        }
      }]
    }
  }
</script>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initialize"></script>
```

Comment: thankyou, however if i put the jsondata in a script the map still doesn't load, however there are no errors in the console. Yet if I try link it to the json file, the map still doesn't load but I get the "initialize is not a function" error again. I'm so confused because running your code snippet on here works, yet not when I write it on mine

Comment: You did include the load of the JSON data (`$.getJSON("'FHRS_json.json'", function(json1) {`, I removed that in the example).

Comment: yeah iadded it on the line above ($.each (jsondata......) and change the json1 to jsonData. is that right?